# writing xml file for the checked values of treeview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, treeview

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="true" ShowExpandCollapse="true">

<Nodes>
<asp:TreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="True" Text="Server1">
  <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="MBS1" />
  <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="MBS2" />
</asp:TreeNode>
<asp:TreeNode Value="Child2" Text="Server2" />
<asp:TreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="True" Text="MBS3">
  <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="MBS4" />
</asp:TreeNode>
 </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
</div>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreateXML" runat="server" onclick="btnCreateXML_Click" 
        Text="Create XML" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Xml;

 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: OnTreeClick();");
}
protected void btnCreateXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    XmlNode Parent = doc.CreateElement("Parent");
    XmlNode Child = doc.CreateElement("Child");
    doc.Save(path);
    string temp;
    char[] al = new char[5];
    foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
    {
        //temp = (node.Text).ToString();
        Child.InnerText = node.Text;
        Parent.AppendChild(Child);

        Response.Write(node.Text);
       // al[node] += al[node];

    }        
 }
}
```

I do have asp.net TreeView control,when i do check the nodes, i can get those checked values from code behind on click event of btnCreateXML.
The Values that I would get into the node.Text, I want to create XML file for it. How to acheive this(only for the selected nodes )?
Any help would be greatful!

Comment: What xml schema would you use to store it? If you have tried something in that direction, showing the code would help.

Comment: Im not aware of how to store, but I want it to be in hierachical manner like parent & child in treeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**aspx file:**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True" ExpandDepth="1">
     <Nodes>
     <asp:TreeNode Text="Entire">
          <asp:TreeNode Text="VM">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="MBS1">   
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="PF1"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>


        <asp:TreeNode Text="VM2">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="MBS2"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="PF2"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>

    </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

**code behind:**

protected void btnCreateXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start writer
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/" + "XMLFile" + ".xml"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        //Start XM DOcument
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        //ROOT Element
        writer.WriteStartElement("MBServerList");
        string temp;
        writer.WriteStartElement("SelectedNodedsInfo");
        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
        {
            temp = (node.Text).ToString();

```
        if (node.Checked)
        {     
           if (node.Depth == 0)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Scanning Entire Tree");
                    writer.WriteString(node.Text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    break;   
                 }

            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {


              {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Server");
                    writer.WriteString(node.Text);


                    foreach (TreeNode cnode in node.ChildNodes)
                    {

                        if (cnode.Checked)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Store");
                            writer.WriteString(cnode.Text);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((node.Depth == 1)||(node.Depth == 2) && (node.Parent.Checked == false))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Server");

                    writer.WriteString(node.Parent.Text);

                    writer.WriteStartElement("Store");
                    writer.WriteString(node.Text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }

        }


    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    lblResult.Text = "XML File ceated!";


    writer.WriteEndElement();
    //End XML Document
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    //Close writer
    writer.Close();
}
```

Update: To get checked values from treeview(Till Depth level 3),and creating xml file for the same.